# How to upgrade my project from ionic 3.9.2 version to ionic 4 latest version

Tags: node.js, cordova, ionic-framework

I tried to upgrade my project from ionic version 3.9.2 to 4.12 by creating a new project and then moving the old project folders of node_modules,src,plugins,resources,WWW But there are many errors can anyone give a correct way so that i can move my entire project to v4.12. My node.js version is 8.0

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to copy all those folders, but you need to follow this guide: https://ionicframework.com/docs/building/migration

Once you did address all the steps per guide you also need to install all the plugins and other dependencies specific to your project.